# Web API Performance Tracking

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, performance-testing, webapi

I'm trying to find a tool which helps in performance testing for an action methods in Web API Controller (Basically for a post call from angular code to API). Is it possible to track the performance of code inside the method of API? If so, Can you please help me to do so with any example.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks & Regards, 
Raghu S.

Comment: If it's about testing the performance, in some cases we do it when running e2e by calling the endpoint multiple times and ensuring that the average response time doesn't exceed a threshold. In production, we ingest all the traces in [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) so that we can always find the bottlenecks, check [this blog post](https://medium.com/apaleo-engineering/how-apaleo-improves-api-performance-9c10695740c1) to see how we do it in [apaleo](https://apaleo.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

There are following options:

1. Use [microbenchmarking library for C#](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-benchmarking-csharp-code-with-benchmark-dot-net)
2. Use [C# code profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)
3. Use a 3rd-party load testing tool like [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) to put the load onto your API endpoint simulating hundreds/thousands of users simultaneously accessing the endpoint, check out [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for more details
4. Any combination of all above